# GAE + GWT Servlet without authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, authentication

I'm developing a web application using Google App Engine and GWT.
I'm using the provided authentication with Google Accounts, so my web.xml contains these lines:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I need a particular servlet to be free from Google Authentication, because it will be called by Android devices. Please do not suggest a way to authenticate the device because it will not suit my needs.

How can I set up my project so that everything is secured under authentication and just one servlet is not?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just:

1)modify the url of the contraint

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

2) move everything into /protected

3) put the android stuff someplace else ... either in / or an new folder /android